# MessageBox in C# showing error

Tags: c#, messagebox

I was attempting to add `MessageBox.Show(Message);` and it was not found in my C# .net web application (button click method and also in `Page_Load`).An error showing like

> *'The name 'MessageBox' does not exist in the current context'*

Do I need to add any assembly reference for this? (I am using .net framework 4). Is there any alternative method for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use This:

```
System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(Page), "alert", "alert('" + Message + "')", true);
```

Hope This help.

Answer (score 5):

The key words in your description are

> web application

This functionality is only available in client (WinForms, WPF) based applications, not ASP.NET. To do this in a web app you will need to use Javascript, as illustrated in [this previous Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220537/display-confirmation-box-in-asp-net-using-javascript).

Answer (score 3):

`System.Windows.MessageBox` is used in **WPF applications** and `System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox` is used in **Windows Form applications** but your project is **WebApplication** so you don't have access to any of them.

Comment: really!!! all you need to do is add the reference of System.windows.Forms in the project and MessageBox.Show() will work. Try it in any Asp.net application. But I am not sure what will happen after deploying in IIS and then using from non MS-OS

Comment: @NewtonSheikh for more clarification you may have a look at other answers for this post.

Answer (score 2):

The `MessageBox` class in the `System.Windows.Forms` namespace is usable from `Windows Forms` and Not ASP.NET Web Forms.